# How to have figures only on left pages and text only the right ones?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, positioning, organisation

EDIT: This post was associated with this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707118/figure-page-float-preferably-on-even-pages/707136#707136)
I kind of understood Mr Carlisle's solution, tested it and it seems to work in my case. However, I can't figure out how to properly insert my own graphics instead of the "rules" used for the example.

Whenever I build this snippet:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\write300{float on page \thepage}
\includegraphics[width=10cm, height=7cm]{sycamore.jpeg}
\caption{Sycamore}
\end{figure}
```

The document is built but won't display the figure at all. I also can't figure out the role of the command "write" here, maybe it has do do with it. I'd be really glad if you could explain it a bit further.

Thanks again,
Antoine

The issue I am facing is pretty similar to the ones described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/figures-on-left-pages-text-on-right-ones-with-class-book-numbering-only-on-rig) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356789/floats-in-a-setting-figures-left-text-right-numbering-right-only).
However I couldn't make these solutions work + I'm facing another issue.

I'm writing a thesis in which I use figures. I want pages on the left to be either blank (rare) or to contain the figures referenced in the next page in terms of numbering (It doesn't have to be automatic, I can do the referencing manually since it seems pretty hard to automatize this way).

I've been looking at floats but couldn't make it work properly.
Has anyone got a code snippet that could simply force figures to appear on the left and leave the rest of the page blank so that text only fills the right one ?

I hope I didn't misunderstand the way LaTeX pages and positioning work but I'm sure someone has faced this issue before.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707118/figure-page-float-preferably-on-even-pages/707136#707136